# mvc3 html.renderpartial on master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

im getting the following exception for use into a master page the helper html.renderpartial(). This works on mvc views that uses this master page, but im trying to execute an old aspx webform page that uses the same masterpage. And here comes following exception:

***A ViewMasterPage can be used only with content pages that derive from ViewPage or ViewPage.***

This is the code of my master page:

```
<body>
    <%Html.RenderPartial("PartialView"); %>
    <div style="background-color:Aqua;">

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like to render some partialviews on my master page. Is it possible?

Comment: Your title says mvc3, but your tags indicate mvc2 - they should be consistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using Razor bulit into MVC 3. A detailed blog post about it can be found [here](http://cnug.co.in/blogs/shijuv/archive/2010/07/29/aspx-and-razor-view-engines-in-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx)

> You can select ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application (APSX) for a pre-defined template for using ASPX syntax in the view pages and can use ASP.NET MVC 3 Web Application (Razor) for writing view pages with Razor syntax. In this post, I am creating two ASP.NET MVC 3 projects with the two different project templates so that we can easily compare the syntax between ASPX and Razor that would be helpful to learn Razor syntax.